# React native: How can i hidden area outside modal

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog

I have floating button with multiple layers background.

How can i disable area of floating button outside modal ( button use position: absolute )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the modal container, you can use `overflow: hidden` to hide any overflowing content.

Like so:

```
.modal{
    /* 
        other css properties 
    */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

However in doing so, you will also be hiding **all** other content that overflows. If this is a problem for you, create a container around the object you want hidden, and position it on the bottom right of your modal, with a fixed width. Once you've done that, add the `overflow: hidden` property to that container's **CSS**.